# React native : Component nothing was returned from the render (UiKitten)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I have this problem, my code works well but if I put an `Accessory Right or Left` I get the error `Nothing was returned from the render`. On other screen it works perfectly but on this screen it's impossible. There are some things that i really don't understand with UIKItten. Thank you for your help.

```
  userChange = () =>  {
    this.state.navigation.navigate('Login', {noAutoConnect : true});
  }

  Disconnect = () => {
    <TopNavigationAction icon={Quit} onPress={this.userChange}/>
  }
  
  render() {    
    return (
        <>
          <TopNavigation style={{ borderWidth: 1 }} title='Acceuil' alignment='center' accessoryLeft = {this.Disconnect}  />
            <View style = {style.lay}>
              <Button size = "giant" onPress = {this.navigateArticles} status = "danger"><Text>Accéder à mes Pdf</Text></Button>
            </View>
       </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` in `Disconnect` function.

```
Disconnect = () => {
    return <TopNavigationAction icon={Quit} onPress={this.userChange}/>
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But i don't understand why i need a return on this screen and not for the other for a same function

Comment: @Dirk Because in this case `accessoryLeft` expects some UI element that's why you need to return something from `Disconnect` function. Passing the only reference is not enough.

Comment: If you want to update the state or do any other stuff then there is no need to return something.

Comment: Ok so i guess that `navigation.goBack()` and `navigation.navigate()` are not considered like similar. it's why it works well on my others screens. Thank you a lot !